# GNUCASH sort transactions by check number

Tags: gnucash

By default, gnucash lists the check register transactions by date. I want to change that to go in a descending order based on the check number.

Is that possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click anywhere in the register and select `Sort By...`

Select `Number` and check `Reverse Order`

Check `Save Sort Order` if you want this to be the default sort order every time you open the register for this account